# Move HashMap across Spring Batch step

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

Currently i am working on writing a batch, which gets the data from couple of source flat files,DB and pushing it to NoSQL. I am facing a challenge while moving the collection data particularly HashMap which if fetched from a Database and stores the metadata of a field in the flat file, its kind of metadata for a particular user. In the flat file we have the daily generated data which we are scanning after every 30mins and pushing it to NoSQL. I want to merge one field from the data base to the entity which we are pushing into the NoSQL.
Current approach which we are trying out is, to get the list of user in step one and write them into a flat file. Then  use this flat file as input to step 2 to get the data from the database and generate a HashMap, which i am serializing and storing it into flat file. Then later in the Step where we are pushing the data to NoSQL, i am again de-serializing this Hashmap and using it there in that step. I am not sure of the performance of this approach on heavy load as we have to meet the SLA of 30mins.
Can you guys please suggest if there is any other approach to achieve this scenario. As per Docs we its not good to have such  huge data in StepContext or JobContext in spring Batch. 
Any Suggestion are most welcome.Thanks in advance. Please do let me know if any more info is required.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Batch provides a way to [pass data from step to step](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/patterns.html#passingDataToFutureSteps)

Store it in the step context:

```
ExecutionContext stepContext = this.stepExecution.getExecutionContext();
stepContext.put("someKey", someObject);
```

Promote it to the job context:

```
<!-- add this as a listener in the step above -->
<beans:bean id="promotionListener" class="org.spr....ExecutionContextPromotionListener">
    <beans:property name="keys" value="someKey"/>
</beans:bean>
```

Retrieve the job execution in the next step:

```
JobExecution jobExecution = stepExecution.getJobExecution();
ExecutionContext jobContext = jobExecution.getExecutionContext();
this.someObject = jobContext.get("someKey");
```